# Не редактируется CSS для мобильной версии

Tags: css, выравнивание, адаптивность

Есть код, при редактировании для мобильной версии CSS никак не реагирует. Ниже скриншот. Надо чтобы кнопка и текст с заголовком был посередине
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 799px) { 
.ban_main {background:rgb(16,213,76);background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(16,213,76,1) 38%, rgba(18,174,65,1) 100%); width:100%; padding:70px 0; position: relative;}    
    .ban_main_wrap {justify-content: center; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 20px 0 20px; position: absolute; top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}
    .ban_main_block {display: flex; align-items: center; align-content: center; text-align: center;}
    .ban_main_left {flex-basis:auto;}
    .ban_main_right {display: none;}
    .ban_main_right img{max-height:250px;}
    .ban_main_title {width:100%; text-align: center;}
    .ban_main_title h1{font-size:10px; color:#fff; font-weight:900; font-family: 'Ubuntu Bold';}
    .ban_main_text {width:100%; color:#fff; font-size:12px;  text-align: center;}
    .ban_main_bnt {width:100%; margin:30px 0 20px 0;}
    .ban_main_bnt a {background:#fff; border-radius:4px; color:#1d1f22; font-size:16px; padding:100px 50px;}
    .ban_main_bnt a:hover {text-decoration:none; opacity: 0.8;}
    .man_h2 {float:center; width:100%; text-align:center; font-size:12px; margin:0 auto; font-weight:700; padding:20px 0;}
}
```

Comment: добавьте код к своему вопросу в читаемом виде

Comment: `float:center` -- это как?

Comment: --А что не так?